# How to create yes no confirm box instead of ok cancel upon button click in Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create yes no confirm box instead of ok cancel upon button click in Javascript/Jquery ?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Answer (score -2):

> The Ok, Cancel alert box is shown by the browser.  In Android, there are functions `JSAlert()` and `JSPrompt()` which only get the message of alert box not the button.

So, Simple answer **You're unable do that**

**Solution**

---

You can do that by creating alert box self, by programming yourself using `Js/JQuery and css`. Yeah you also can download some examples from **Google**
I have found this try it [Custom Alert Box. Yes/No](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28812/Custom-Alert-Boxes-using-JavaScript-and-the-DOM)